# Weird line behaviour with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, timeserieschart

I'm plotting temperature-measurements over time in python. In the plot, you can see these weird cross-lines for the first third of the timeframe.

[image]

What are those? I checked for duplicate timestamps, but that's not the problem. My code is here:

```py
output["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(output["datetime"], infer_datetime_format=True)
output.set_index("datetime", inplace=True)
output = output.dropna(how='any', axis=0)
output = output.drop(output[output.temperature >= 30].index)
plt.plot(output, label="temperature")
plt.legend()
plt.minorticks_on()
xformatter = mdates.DateFormatter(r'%d.%m.%y')
plt.gcf().axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(xformatter)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

"output" is a Dataframe I get from the database:

```
                        temperature
datetime
2020-12-14 11:18:02.729         8.1
2020-12-14 11:20:32.730         8.1
2020-12-14 11:23:02.736         8.2
2020-12-14 11:25:32.635         8.3
2020-12-14 11:28:02.628         8.1
```

Comment: is your data sorted correctly by the date

Comment: Try `plt.plot(output.sort_index(), label="temperature")`

Comment: @StupidWolf yes, I tried it and it's showing me the same thing

Comment: @PatrickFitzGerald Thanks! That fixed it! It didn't work with `sort_values()` but now it looks good.